# Auto Arima not giving output (running but no output)

Tags: r, finance, arima

I am trying to model daily adjusted closing values for Dow Jones and SP500. When I ran this code for my SP5000 dataset it ran in a few seconds. However when I do it for Dow Jones it runs and never stops. I've waited 30 mins and it still shows its running. I have roughly 2,500 rows of data, so I am not sure why I am not getting an output instantly. I am modeling ARIMA so I can GARCH model later on.

`library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(TSA)
library(forecast)
dj<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/DJI.csv", header=T, sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
dj$Date <- as.Date(dj$Date, "%m-%d-%Y")
auto.arima(djts)`

Comment: Setting the parameter `auto.arima(djts, trace = TRUE)` will give you a hint of what is going on inside the arima solver. Probably the automatically selected maximum orders of p, d, q are high, so the solver checks too many models

Comment: I have done this before auto.arima(djts, stepwise=F, approximation=T, trace=T) where it listed the first 8 combinations within 10 mins and just kept running.

Comment: Actually doing just Trace worked! Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful for other members if you add the solution you came to